# MySQL query doesn't sort calculated values

Tags: mysql, sorting, time

I have a longer, more complex code and I want to get the newest entry from the table, but I receive the oldest one. I tried: `MIN(date), Max(date) desc`, and `asc`. It doesn't work. Does my code require a special solution?

```
SELECT stock_id,
       stocks.name,
       DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS date,
       price, pxchange,
       CONCAT(round(pxpct*100, 4), '%') AS pxpct, 
       stocks.stockmarket, 
       stockmarkets.id
FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN stock_id <> @pxticker THEN @pxclose := NULL END,
               p.*, 
               (price - @pxclose) AS pxchange, 
               (price - @pxclose) / @pxclose AS pxpct, 
               (@pxclose := price), 
               (@pxticker := stock_id)
        FROM   quotations p CROSS JOIN 
               (SELECT @pxclose := NULL, @pxticker := stock_id
                FROM   quotations
                ORDER  BY stock_id, date
                LIMIT  1) AS a
        ORDER  BY stock_id, date) AS b
LEFT   JOIN stocks       ON stock_id = stocks.id
LEFT   JOIN stockmarkets ON stockmarkets.id = stocks.stockmarket 
WHERE  stocks.stockmarket = (SELECT id FROM stockmarkets WHERE short ='".$q."')
GROUP  BY stock_id
ORDER  BY stock_id, MIN(date) ASC
```

I am thinking and working since hours, tried and tried. But nothing seems to help.

Thanks to anyone who can help. I would'nt be surprise if I am slow on the uptake.

--
EDIT - Example

What I got but don't want.

```
4   Facebook, Inc.          2014-02-24 14:43:49     7   NULL    NULL    1   1
5   Tesla Motors, Inc.  2014-02-24 14:59:28     7   NULL    NULL    1   1
```

What I want (sample values, the date - timestamp - is important).

```
4   Facebook, Inc.          2014-03-10 22:33:39     50  NULL    NULL    1   1
5   Tesla Motors, Inc.  2014-03-10 22:52:28     20  NULL    NULL    1   1
```

With the syntax above I want to get the latest quotations of every stock which I connected to NASDAQ (in this example). But I always get the oldest, first quotations I have inserted in my table 'quotations'.

EDIT
[image: quotations_table]

EDIT 2 - code

```
SELECT stock_id,
       stocks.name,
       DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS date,
       price, pxchange,
       CONCAT(round(pxpct*100, 4), '%') AS pxpct, 
       stocks.stockmarket, 
       stockmarkets.id
FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN stock_id <> @pxticker THEN @pxclose := NULL END,
               p.*, 
               (price - @pxclose) AS pxchange, 
               (price - @pxclose) / @pxclose AS pxpct, 
               (@pxclose := price), 
               (@pxticker := stock_id)
        FROM   quotations p CROSS JOIN 
               (SELECT @pxclose := NULL, @pxticker := stock_id
                FROM   quotations
                ORDER  BY date, stock_id
                LIMIT  1) AS a
        ORDER  BY date, stock_id) AS b
LEFT   JOIN stocks       ON stock_id = stocks.id
LEFT   JOIN stockmarkets ON stockmarkets.id = stocks.stockmarket 
WHERE  stocks.stockmarket = (SELECT id FROM stockmarkets WHERE short ='NASDAQ')
GROUP  BY stock_id
ORDER  BY date, stock_id
```

Here is a fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff809/44
Not exactly the same data, but the code I am working with. And still the same problem: how to get the latest entry?

EDIT - screenshots for information about structure
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Here are screenshots about the content and the structure of the used tables. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I'm not a mysql guru, but since you have date fields in multiple tables, I think you want to qualify the date sort by the table from which you want to sort.

Comment: Bit more clarity needed mate.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: added an example. Hope it makes it clearer what the problem is.

Comment: In your select from quotations you aren't ordering by date desc????

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Could you please explain, what you want to say?
I always thought I have to order at the end of the syntax. But maybe I mistake your meaning.

Comment: Well the point I was making you appear to have edited out...

Comment: @TonyHopinson You mean this lines of code?
               (SELECT #pxclose := NULL, #pxticker := stock_id
                FROM   quotations
                ORDER  BY date, stock_id
                LIMIT  1) AS a
?
E.g writing
               (SELECT #pxclose := NULL, #pxticker := stock_id
                FROM   quotations
                ORDER  BY date DESC, stock_id
                LIMIT  1) AS a
Don't work. Seems like. But: I'll try to tomorrow. Am tired and when I am tired I do most mistakes. Hope I can solve and then I show the solution code.

Attention: changed pxclose for discussion here.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: thank you, it works partly. I get the latest price. But pxchange and pxpct aren't the latest one.
I tried in a fiddle (added to my question above) too, which uses the code I use for my SQL, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want oldest record then the order by clause should have date first.
Change the following

```
ORDER BY stock_id, date DESC
```

with

```
ORDER BY date DESC, stock_id
```

Comment: Also, if you only want one record, add:

"LIMIT 1"

After your ORDER BY.

Comment: Seems it doesn't help. No change.